Subbing a class name for a table name in ActiveRecord query
I've got this line:
factory.workers.where.not(confirmed_at:nil).where(job_roles: {heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false}).pluck(:work_capacity)

But the association table job_roles depends on the class name of the factory, and I've got 5 types of factories. So if factory.class.name == "DistributionCenter" then job_roles would actually be distribution_center_roles, or if factory.class.name == "AutomotiveAssemblyPlant" then job_roles would be automotive_assembly_plant_roles etc.
Is there any way to sub the class name in the association table name in the ActiveRecord query code, so that instead of it saying job_roles, it says distribution_center_roles or automotive_assembly_plant_roles (etc), based on the class name of factory?
liiiike
factory.workers.where.not(confirmed_at:nil).where((factory.class.name + "_roles").string_to_tablename_rails_method: {heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false}).pluck(:work_capacity)

or do I have to do:
if factory.is_a?(DistributionCenter)
  factory.workers.where.not(confirmed_at:nil).where(distribution_center_roles: {heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false}).pluck(:work_capacity)
elsif factory.is_a?(AutomotiveAssemblyPlant)
  factory.workers.where.not(confirmed_at:nil).where(automotive_assembly_plant_roles: {heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false}).pluck(:work_capacity)
etc


I would use ActiveModel::Naming and a reflection if you want to do this in a less hacky way:
module RoleScoped
  def with_roles(**conditions)
     reflect_on_assocation(:"#{model_name.singular}_roles")
       .compute_class
       .where(conditions)
  end
end

class DistributionCenter < ApplicationModel
  extend RoleScoped
end

class AutomotiveAssemblyPlant < ApplicationModel
  extend RoleScoped
end

factory.workers
       .where.not(confirmed_at:nil) 
       .merge(factory.class.with_roles(heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false))
       .pluck(:work_capacity)

This avoids making assumptions about the tablenames. Even better would be to name the assocation the same thing in the two classes so that you don't have to monkey around in the first place.
class DistributionCenter
  has_many :roles, class_name: 'DistributionCenterRole'
end

class AutomotiveAssemblyPlant
  has_many :roles, class_name: 'AutomotiveAssemblyPlantRole'
end


factory.workers
       .where.not(confirmed_at:nil) 
       .merge(factory.roles.where(heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false))
       .pluck(:work_capacity)


Second one is beautiful, first one is next level that I'll have to read up on

reflect_on_assocation(:"#{model_name.singular}_roles") is really just a way to get the metadata about an association. And then compute_class gets the target class of the association.

If the name of the table is based on model name, you can just underscore it
job_roles = :"#{factory.class.name.underscore}_roles"

If some namespace is used for the model, you probably need also parameterize
job_roles = :"#{factory.class.name.undercore.parameterize(separator: '_')}_roles"

Compare:
Asdf::FooBar.name.underscore
# => "asdf/foo_bar"

Asdf::FooBar.name.underscore.parameterize(separator: '_')
# => "asdf_foo_bar"

If the name of the table is based on table name, you can tableize it
job_roles = :"#{factory.class.name.tableize}_roles"

It is also possible to use ActiveRecord::Base::table_name
It will also work even you customly redefine table_name inside the model or use custom table_name_prefix / table_name_suffix
job_roles = :"#{factory.class.table_name}_roles"

After that you can apply it to your query
factory.workers.where.not(confirmed_at:nil).where(job_roles => {heavy_lifting:true, sensitive_area: false}).pluck(:work_capacity)


While this is one way to do it beware that you're building a pretty brittly solution as this leaves a lot of moving parts dangling out from the models.
